# AUTO_INCREMENT in MariaDB is kept in memory only

Tags: mariadb

We're currently using MariaDB 10.1 for development. When initializing the database we run a migration script which sets the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for a specific table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

**Motivation**
We run MariaDB in a Docker image for development purposes, i.e. we can destroy and rebuild the database at any time. However this specific table needs to be initialized with that starting value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` row. So we copied the script to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` upon building the Docker image.

However this does not have any affect until an `INSERT` would follow.

From the MariaDB knowledge base:

> Until MariaDB 10.2.3, InnoDB and XtraDB used an auto-increment counter
>   that is stored in memory. When the server restarts, the counter is
>   re-initialized, which cancels the effects of any AUTO_INCREMENT = N
>   option in the table statements.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment-handling-in-xtradbinnodb/

Hwoever I could not find out how to handle this. Which statements or configurations do I have to make in order to be the above SQL statement effective (until we're ready to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2.4 or higher)?

Answer (score 0):

The only use for that `ALTER` is to immediately `INSERT` a row and have it be given the value 1000000.  Once that row is inserted, the clause has no further effect -- unless you delete all the rows and need to restart at that value.

An alternative to it is to explicitly provide the value for the first `INSERT`.

Since I have yet to find a 'valid' reason for ever using the clause, please explain what you are trying to do.  Maybe we can think of a usable workaround.

In the future, I think there will be a change wherein the AI value is persisted in the index.  This is already a feature in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I added the motivation for this statement to the original question.